# Замена и удаление в Регулярных выражениях

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Начал изучать Регулярные выражения поэтому в этом вопросе я только новичок.
Не мог бы кто нибудь из профессионалов показать на нескольких примерах как можно удалить и заменить некоторые символы а адресах урл.

Примеры:

1). На сайте имеются два урл адреса на одно и тоже изображение: одно маленькое, второе большое.

Маленькое изображение - img1.wbstatic.net/tm/new/252000/2525809-1.jpg

Большое изображение - img1.wbstatic.net/big/new/2520000/2525809-1.jpg

Вопрос: Как осуществить замену символов tm на big чтобы получить ссылки на большие изображения?

2). Как удалять из урл адреса некоторые символы? Например удалить -c50/ из урл - static2.ozone.ru/multimedia/boots/c50/1013615627.jpg , чтобы получилось так - static2.ozone.ru/multimedia/boots/1013615627.jpg

3). Как заменить символы в конце урл - cdn6.bigcommerce.com/s-scgdirr/products/19278/images/42481/A823Mleadbrown__45287.1441125443.66.100.jpg?c=2
то есть 66.100 на 1280.1280
чтобы получилось так - cdn6.bigcommerce.com/s-scgdirr/products/19278/images/42481/A823Mleadbrown__45287.1441125443.1280.1280.jpg?c=2

Comment: А на каком языке? Для приведенных вами примеров регулярки не нужны.

Comment: Регулярные выражения никак не могут модифицировать строку с которой работают. Их  задача найти и "выделить" в строке интересующие точки, т.е. подготовить почву для дальнейшей модификации строки средствами языка, в котором они используются. А сама замена на каждом языке программирования пишется по разному. на perl 1й ваш вопрос был бы `s/tm/big/`, на php: `preg_perlace('/tm/','big',$s);`, на JS: `"str".replace(/tm/,'big`)`

Comment: Regex..........

Comment: Что Regex ? так называют сами регулярные выражения - т.е. язык поиска, но не замен. В чем именно вы собираетесь их использовать ? Имейте ввиду, что существует как минимум 4 диалекта регурлярок: PCRE, JS, Python, POSIX и местами они кардинально отличаются.

Comment: регулярные выражения мне неопходимы для парсинга информации

Comment: Это все понятно, но каким именно средством вы пользуетесь что бы эти выражения выполнять ? Кстати обратите внимание на сайт regex101.com на нем можно отлаживать выражения

Comment: Регулярные выражения мне нужны для програмы парсера - Visual Web Ripper, вот скриншот окна для работы с регулярными выражениями - yadi.sk/i/Ukmh0KyznCd9k

Comment: Вот с этого и надо было начинать. Надо документацию на ту программу смотреть, что бы точно сказать что и как в ней с этими выражениями делать. Судя по скриншоту я вообще не вижу куда можно было бы внести на что заменять. То что вы пишите во вторую строку на что менять явно не работает. сначала надо понять куда именно и в каком виде это писать конкретно в этой программе, потому как никакими стандартами на регулярные выражения это не оговаривается и каждая программа реализует это по своему

Comment: @Sherwood Нашел в гугле первая же ссылка по названию вашей программы и 'regex' http://www.visualwebripper.com/Display.aspx?manual_id=946  тут явно видно, что для замены надо написать слово replace на второй строке и на что собственно менять

Comment: в инструкции об этом написано так:
Каждое регулярное выражение действия должно быть указано в двух строках: первая строка должна содержать регулярное выражение шаблон а вторая строка должна содержать оператор действия, которые можно вернуть, заменить или вставить.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Паттерн:

   ```
   (img1\.wbstatic\.net/)tm(/new/\d+/[\d-]+\.jpg)
   ```

   Замена:

   ```
   $1big$2
   ```
2. Паттерн:

   ```
   (static\d+\.ozone\.ru/multimedia/boots/)c50/(\d+.jpg)
   ```

   Замена:

   ```
   $1$2
   ```
3. Паттерн:

   ```
   (cdn\d+.bigcommerce\.com/s-scgdirr/products/\d+/images/\d+/.+\.\d+\.)66\.100(\.jpg\?c=2)
   ```

   Замена:

   ```
   ${1}1280.1280$2
   ```

---

Однако использовать здесь регулярные выражения для замены не имеет смысла - это только лишнее усложнение.

Гораздо лучше регулярными выражениями проверять соответствие url определенному шаблону, а для замены использовать обычную функцию замены, в той или иной форме присутствующую в любом языке программирования:

```cs
"img1.wbstatic.net/tm/new/252000/2525809-1.jpg".Replace("/tm/", "big");

"static2.ozone.ru/multimedia/boots/c50/1013615627.jpg".Replace("c50/", "");

"cdn6.bigcommerce.com/s-scgdirr/products/19278/images/42481/A823Mleadbrown__45287.1441125443.66.100.jpg?c=2"
    .Replace("66.100.jpg", "1280.1280.jpg");
```

---

**Обновлено:**

Скачал и установил указанный вами Visual Web Ripper - специфичная вещь - CCS-селекторов им ну очень не хватает.. Но я не об этом..

"Transformation Script" - это вовсе не как вы выразились "окно для работы с регулярками" - это именно редактор скриптов трансформации. У них собственный простенький язык программирования, служащий для последовательного преобразования текстовых данных.

[image: Окно редактора скриптов трансформации]

Язык этот состоит из одной или множества последовательно идущих пар "строка поиска" и "операция". Строка поиска - да, регулярное выражение. А вот операция - это один из трех основных операторов - return(возврат найденного), replace(его замена), и insert(вставка внутрь текста). Если оператор не задан прямо, то используется select - собственно из-за этого у вас и возникает проблема с "неожиданно появляющимся пробелом".

Как я и писал выше, вам надо было использовать операцию замены - replace:

```
/c50/
replace /

/tm/
replace /big/

66.100.jpg
replace 1280.1280.jpg
```

Для сложных же преобразований, у вас в редакторе есть вкладки C# и VB.NET - они позволяют использовать для преобразований всю мощь Microsoft.NET Framework, с бесчисленным количество библиотек для него.

Comment: Огромное вам спасибо за помощь! Все наглядно теперь и понятней.
Ну тут что не получается маленько. В 1 случае результат получается таким - http://static2.ozone.ru/multimedia/boots/ 1011632837.jpg - присутствует пробел перед названием файла. Во втором примере, результат замены происходит частичный вот такой - /new/2520000/2525809-1.jpg. В третьем примере, результат такой - .jpg?c=2. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: @Sherwood Раз присутствует пробел, значит в строке замены вы этот пробел явно указали. Обратите внимание, у Sergey Rufanov в примере кавычки для замены пустые, т.е. `""` а у вас там скорее всего пробел `" "`. Если строка частично, значит ее кусок вы потеряли, почему - не видя точно что вы делаете сказать нельзя, возможно забыли $1 или скобки. В третьем случае опять же скорее всего забыли $1 $2 и т.п.

Comment: Я не этот код имел в виду - "static2.ozone.ru/multimedia/boots/c50/1013615627.jpg".Replace("c50/", "");
а этот - (static\d+\.ozone\.ru/multimedia/boots/)c50/(\d+.jpg)

Comment: @Sherwood, ответил вам в обновлении к ответу

Comment: Еще раз большое спасибо за исчерпывающие ответы! Очень помогли!